# SQL TRIGGER - overlapping dates in simple prisoner model

Tags: oracle, triggers, overlapping

I have a simple problem, but I am quite new to the SQL.
I have a simple prisons & prisoners model and I need trigger which will provide that my dates will not overlap.

The table (execution of the sentence) has 3 attributes:
1. ID of execution of the sentence ("ID_exec")
2. from ("from") 
3. to ("to")

I need to fix that one sentence of the prisoners will not overlap his another sentence.
For example - He will have sentence (1st of August 2011 - 1st of August 2031) and new sentence should not be overlaping this date.

Thank You for Your answers.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need also `prisonerID` in your `sentence` table.

```
create table sentence
( id number,
  prisonerID number,
  fromDate date,
  toDate date);
```

Without it, It would be hard to identify which prisoner's sentence you deal with.
The criteria to reject would be:

```
:NEW.toDate > fromDate AND
:NEW.FromDate < toDate
```

If some record is returned by the above criteria - insert should be rejected. The criteria comes from requirement that start time or end time cannot be inside existing period and they cannot include such period. Breaking this on parts - new fromDate has to be sooner than old ToDate and new toDate has to be later than fromDate.

```
  create or replace trigger sentence_reject_existing
  before insert 
  on sentence
  for each row 
  declare
   vCount NUMBER;
   begin
     select count(*)
      into vCount
     from sentence 
     where prisonerID = :NEW.prisonerID and
           :NEW.Todate > fromDate    and
           :New.FromDate < toDate   ;

     if vCount > 0 then
        raise_application_error(-20005,'Prisoner is already in prison');
     end if;

   end;
```